# Relational database join only showing one row

Tags: mysql

I have the SQL Query:

```
SELECT B.branchNumber, B.buildingName, SUM(CASE WHEN PI.offerPrice > 0 THEN PI.offerPrice * PI.quantity ELSE price * PI.quantity END) AS total
FROM `purchase` 
INNER JOIN `product` on purchase.productCode = product.productCode 
INNER JOIN `branch` B on purchase.branchNumber = B.branchNumber 
INNER JOIN `purchase info` PI on purchase.productCode = PI.productCode AND purchase.purchaseID = PI.purchaseID
```

Which is returning only one `total` As the `INNER JOIN` only shows the matching columns with `total`.  When I remove the:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN PI.offerPrice > 0 THEN PI.offerPrice * PI.quantity ELSE price * PI.quantity END) AS total
```

It returns several rows. How can I get this to return all the rows with the `total`s?

Comment: Try using LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: I have tried but no luck! I think I need to nest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would seem to be missing a `"GROUP BY B.BranchNumber, B.BuildingName"` clause at the end of your statement